# is ifelse ever appropriate in a non-vectorized situation and vice-versa?

Tags: r

(Background info: `ifelse` evaluates *both* of the expressions, even though only one will be returned. EDIT: This is an incorrect statement. See Tommy's reply)

Is there any example where it makes sense to use `ifelse` in a non-vectorized situation? I think that "readability" could be a valid answer when we don't care about small efficiency gains, but besides that, is it ever faster/equivalent/better-in-some-other-way to use `ifelse` when an `if` and then `else` would do the job?

Similarly, if I have a vectorized situation, is `ifelse` always the best tool to use? It seems strange that both expressions are evaluated. Is it ever faster to loop through one by one and do a normal `if` and then `else`? I'm guessing it would make sense only if evaluating the expressions took a really long time. Is there any other alternative that would not involve an explicit loop?

Thanks

Answer (score 16, accepted):

First, `ifelse` does **NOT** always evaluate both expressions - only if there are both `TRUE` and `FALSE` elements in the test vector.

```
ifelse(TRUE, 'foo', stop('bar')) # "foo"
```

And in my opinion:

`ifelse` should **not** be used in a non-vectorized situation. It is *always slower* and *more error prone* to use `ifelse` over `if` / `else`:

```
# This is fairly common if/else code
if (length(letters) > 0) letters else LETTERS

# But this "equivalent" code will yield a very different result - TRY IT!
ifelse(length(letters) > 0, letters, LETTERS)
```

In vectorized situations though, `ifelse` can be a good choice - but beware that the length and attributes of the result might not be what you expect (as above, and I consider `ifelse` broken in that respect).

Here's an example: `tst` is of length 5 and has a class. I'd expect the result to be of length 10 and have no class, but that isn't what happens - it gets an incompatible class and length 5!

```
# a logical vector of class 'mybool'
tst <- structure(1:5 %%2 > 0, class='mybool')

# produces a numeric vector of class 'mybool'!
ifelse(tst, 101:110, 201:210)
#[1] 101 202 103 204 105
#attr(,"class")
#[1] "mybool"
```

Why would I expect the length to be 10? Because most functions in R "cycle" the shorter vector to match the longer:

```
1:5 + 1:10 # returns a vector of length 10.
```

...But `ifelse` only cycles the yes/no arguments to match the length of the tst argument.

Why would I expect the class (and other attributes) to **not** be copied from the test object? Because `<` which returns a logical vector does not copy class and attributes from its (typically numeric) arguments. It doesn't do that because it would typically be very wrong.

```
1:5 < structure(1:10, class='mynum') # returns a logical vector without class
```

Finally, can it be more efficient to "do it yourself"? Well, it seems that `ifelse` is not a primitive like `if`, and it needs some special code to handle `NA`. If you don't have `NA`s, it can be faster to do it yourself.

```
tst <- 1:1e7 %%2 == 0
a <- rep(1, 1e7)
b <- rep(2, 1e7)
system.time( r1 <- ifelse(tst, a, b) )            # 2.58 sec

# If we know that a and b are of the same length as tst, and that
# tst doesn't have NAs, then we can do like this:
system.time( { r2 <- b; r2[tst] <- a[tst]; r2 } ) # 0.46 secs

identical(r1, r2) # TRUE
```

Comment: thank you! I don't have time to look this over now, but I will do so later tonight. Thanks for your comments and examples.

Comment: Note that `ifelse` does perform vector recycling - if either of the `yes` or `no` variables are unequal in length to `test`, they will get recycle.  This means your test code at the end of your example will only yield identical results if all of the vector are of equal length.  Try for example this input data: `tst <- sample(c(TRUE, FALSE), 1e2, replace=TRUE); a <- 1:100; b <- -(1:50);`

Comment: @Andrie - thanks, I clarified that above. Also added example where non-vectorized `ifelse` gives surprising results.

Comment: @Andrie good point Andrie. Thanks for noticing that. Thanks for updating, Tommy.

Answer (score 5):

On your second point, how do you define "best"? I think `ifelse()` is one of the more readable solutions, but may not always be the fastest. Specifically, I've found that writing out boolean conditions and adding them together can give you some performance benefits. Here's a quick example:

```
> x <- rnorm(1e6)
> system.time(y1 <- ifelse(x > 0,1,2))
   user  system elapsed 
   0.46    0.08    0.53 
> system.time(y2 <- (x > 0) * 1 + (x <= 0) * 2)
   user  system elapsed 
   0.06    0.00    0.06 
> identical(y1, y2)
[1] TRUE
```

So, if speed is your biggest concern, the boolean approach may be better. However, for most of my purposes - I've found `ifelse()` quick enough and is easy to grok. Your miles may vary obviously.

Comment: I will shamefully admit to writing the boolean version not just because it's fast but because it's  31337 .  But, seriously, once you get used to it, the code is just as easy to read and understand as code using if.

Comment: It is even faster to use `y3 <- (x <= 0) + 1` since it doesn't include a redundant test.