# if function and length of the logical vector

Tags: r, if-statement

I have a dataframe where the dates are given as hydrological years (October to September). To change this I am trying to use a if statement:

```
if(cet$month== 10|cet$month==11|cet$month==12) 
  cet$year <- substr(as.character(cet[,2]),1,4) else
  cet$year <- substr(as.character(cet[,2]),6,9)
```

but I get an error: 
`the condition has length > 1 and only the first element will be used`

Reading the "if" help file I realized that the condition has to be a length-one logical vector. Is there no way of using an "or" with an "if"? All I want is to apply that expression if the month is October, November or December.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`ifelse` is the vectorised version. You can also use `%in%` to reduce the number of statements.

```
cet$year <- ifelse(cet$month%in%(10:12), substr(as.character(cet[,2]),1,4), substr(as.character(cet[,2]),6,9))
```

Comment: and as usual `transform` makes things nicer: `cet <- transform(cet,year=ifelse(month %in% 10:12, substr(name,1,4), substr(name,6,9)))` (assuming the second column is labeled `name`)

Comment: @sbg - you might want to look at this question for some gotchas when using `ifelse`: http://stackoverflow.com/a/8190389/662787

Answer (score 0):

Ok, here's a reproducible example that should help to clarify things:

```
 # generate some vector
 x <- c(1,2,4,4,5,5,6,6,6)
 # have a check using OR, return values
 x[x == 2 | x == 1]
 ## or return TRUE / FALSE
 (x == 2 | x == 1)
```

or check `?ifelse`

EDIT: Note that for characters you need to use "", like  `x == "yourchars" | x == "someotherchars"`

Here's also some simple reference and how to work with operators: [QuickR](http://www.statmethods.net/management/operators.html)

Comment: Shouldn't that last line be `(x==2|x==1)` , i.e. not the `[` opr?

Answer (score -1):

the OR instruction is double pipes

`|` => `||` in the `if()`

Comment: Read the R documentation.  `||` is different from `|`