# Break out of the inner loop

Tags: r, if-statement, for-loop, break

I am trying to nest one loop in another and break out of the inner loop and move on with the outer loop when a condition is met. My dataframes `a_2011` and `TRS` are of the following form:

```
a_2011<- data.frame(c("10N11W11", "10N11W11", "10N12W7", "10N13W22" , "10N14W1"))
TRS <- data.frame(c("10N12W7","10N13W22","10N14W1", "10N15W33"))

for (i in 1:nrow(a_2011))
{
  a_2011$City[i] <- 1
  for (j in 1:nrow(TRS))
  {
    if ( as.character(a_2011[i,1]) ==  as.character(TRS[j,1]) )
    {
      break
    }
    else
    {
      a_2011$City[i] <- 0
    }
  }
}
```

The desired output for `a_2011$City` is a column vector of 2 zeros followed by 3 ones. But the code above is not skipping the commands after the break statement in the inner loop.

Would appreciate any help in figuring out what is wrong here.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The problem is that the inner loop only breaks if the *first* row of TRS matches. To make your code work you'd have to do like this:

```
a_2011<- data.frame(c("10N11W11", "10N11W11", "10N12W7", "10N13W22" , "10N14W1"))
TRS <- data.frame(c("10N12W7","10N13W22","10N14W1", "10N15W33"))

for (i in 1:nrow(a_2011))
{
    flag <- 0
    for (j in 1:nrow(TRS))
    {
        if ( as.character(a_2011[i,1]) ==  as.character(TRS[j,1]) )
        {
             flag <- 1
             break
        }
    }
    a_2011$City[i] <- flag
}
```

You can remove the need for the inner loop like this:

```
a_2011<- data.frame(c("10N11W11", "10N11W11", "10N12W7", "10N13W22" , "10N14W1"))
TRS <- data.frame(c("10N12W7","10N13W22","10N14W1", "10N15W33"))

for (i in 1:nrow(a_2011))
{
    flag <- any(as.character(a_2011[i,1]) ==  as.character(TRS[,1]))
    a_2011$City[i] <- as.numeric(flag)
}
```

..And then to simplify it further, you can remove the outer loop too:

```
a_2011<- data.frame(c("10N11W11", "10N11W11", "10N12W7", "10N13W22" , "10N14W1"))
TRS <- data.frame(c("10N12W7","10N13W22","10N14W1", "10N15W33"))

a_2011$City <- as.numeric(a_2011[[1]] %in% TRS[[1]])
```

Answer (score 5):

You don't need a loop to achieve this in R.

```
a_2011<- c("10N11W11", "10N11W11", "10N12W7", "10N13W22" , "10N14W1")
TRS   <- data.frame(c("10N12W7","10N13W22","10N14W1", "10N15W33")

city  <- rep(0, 5)
city[a_2011 %in% TRS] <- 1
```

Answer (score 4):

You don't need a loop at all.  This is what `ifelse` is for.

```
a_2011$City <- ifelse( a_2011[,1] %in% TRS[,1], 1, 0)
```

Comment: `ifelse` works well here, but in general, be careful: http://stackoverflow.com/a/8190389/662787