# Create data.frame conditional on another df without for loop

Tags: r, for-loop, dataframe, conditional-statements

I'm trying to create a data.frame that takes different values depending on the value of a reference data.frame. I only know how to do this with a "for loop", but have been advised to avoid for loops in R... and my actual data have ~500,000 rows x ~200 columns.

```
a <- as.data.frame(matrix(rbinom(10,1,0.5),5,2,dimnames=list(c(1:5),c("a","b"))))
b <- data.frame(v1=c(2,10,12,5,11,3,4,14,2,13),v2=c("a","b","b","a","b","a","a","b","a","b"))
c <- as.data.frame(matrix(0,5,2))

for (i in 1:5){
  for(j in 1:2){
    if(a[i,j]==1){
      c[i,j] <- mean(b$v1[b$v2==colnames(a)[j]])
    } else {
      c[i,j]= mean(b$v1)
    }}}
c
```

I create data.frame "c" based on the value in each cell, and the corresponding column name, of data.frame "a". 
Is there another way to do this? Indexing? Using data.table? Maybe *apply* functions? 
Any and all help is greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
(a == 0) * mean(b$v1) + t(t(a) * c(tapply(b$v1, b$v2, mean)))
```

Run in pieces to understand what's happening. Also, note that this assumes ordered names in `a` (and 0's and 1's as entries in it, as per OP).

An alternative to a bunch of `t`'s as above is using `mapply` (this assumes `a` is a `data.frame` or `data.table` and not a `matrix`, while the above doesn't care):

```
(a == 0) * mean(b$v1) + mapply(`*`, a, tapply(b$v1, b$v2, mean))
```

Comment: @dickoa I have a feeling there is a much simpler way of multiplying those two, than the above

Comment: Thank you @eddi, but I'm getting something strange... I would like the average for the factor level = colname(a) from data.frame "b" to be used when a cell in "a" is equal to 1. Your code seems to alternate between the average for factor level "a" and factor level "b" without keeping track of the column name from data.frame "a".

Comment: It's y vert good example of vectorization in R though the removing the call to `t` would be nice. +1

Comment: @seapen Not sure what you mean. I'm pretty sure this does same thing as you for loops (with the caveats above). The names are matched by virtue of `tapply` ordering by the factor (and the assumption that names of `a` are ordered).

Comment: Both of these work perfectly! Thank you @eddi. Ignore my previous comment, I had tried your original code before the first correction (as mentioned by dickoa, I wasn't getting the same as 'c').

Answer (score 1):

```
#subsetting a matrix is faster
res <- as.matrix(a)

#calculate fill-in values outside the loop
in1 <- mean(b$v1)
in2 <- sapply(colnames(a),function(i) mean(b$v1[b$v2==i]))

#loop over columns and use a vectorized approach 
for (i in seq_len(ncol(res))) {
  res[,i] <- ifelse(res[,i]==0, in1, in2[i])
}
```

Comment: +1 Nice approach but `ifelse` is known to be usually slower than traditional `if`...`else` but it looks more compact

Comment: I don't understand your comment. `ifelse` is vectorized, `if` is not. `ifelse` is faster than `if` plus a loop.

Comment: You are right, I'm sorry if vectorized it's faster but in non vectorized situation it's actually slower check this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8190279/is-ifelse-ever-appropriate-in-a-non-vectorized-situation-and-vice-versa?rq=1

Comment: Not related to your answer but I just did a small confusion (vectorization and not) because of a vague souvenir of this thread. In this case, the use of `ifelse` is the way to go. Sorry