# R, Create data.frame conditional on colnames and row entries of existing df

Tags: r, for-loop, dataframe, apply

I have a follow up to this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17708811/create-data-frame-conditional-on-another-df-without-for-loop).

I am creating a data.frame conditional on the column names and specific row entries of an existing data.frame. Below is how I resolved it using a **for loop** (thanks to @Roland's suggestion... the real data violated requirements of @eddi's answer), but it has been running on the actual data set (200x500,000+ rows.cols) for more than two hours now...

(The following generated data.frames are very similar to the actual data.)

```
set.seed(1)
a <- data.frame(year=c(1986:1990),
                events=round(runif(5,0,5),digits=2))
b <- data.frame(year=c(rep(1986:1990,each=2,length.out=40),1986:1990), 
                region=c(rep(c("x","y"),10),rep(c("y","z"),10),rep("y",5)),
                state=c(rep(c("NY","PA","NC","FL"),each=10),rep("AL",5)),
                events=round(runif(45,0,5),digits=2))
d <- matrix(rbinom(200,1,0.5),10,20, dimnames=list(c(1:10), rep(1986:1990,each=4)))
e <- data.frame(id=sprintf("%02d",1:10), as.data.frame(d), 
                region=c("x","y","x","z","z","y","y","z","y","y"), 
                state=c("PA","AL","NY","NC","NC","NC","FL","FL","AL","AL"))


 for (i in seq_len(nrow(d))) {
   for (j in seq_len(ncol(d))) {
     d[i,j] <- ifelse(d[i,j]==0,
                      a$events[a$year==colnames(d)[j]],
                      b$events[b$year==colnames(d)[j] &
                               b$state==e$state[i] &
                               b$region==e$region[i]])
   }
 }
```

Is there a better/faster way to do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A simpler way to do it (I think - it does not involve melting, dcasting and merging) is as follows:

First, your a and b arrays, should be indexed by year (for a) and by year/state/region (for b):

```
at = a$events; names(at) = a$year

bt = tapply(b$events,list(b$year,b$state,b$region),function(x) min(x))
# note, I used min(x) in tapply just to be on the safe side, that the functions always returns a scalar

# we now create the result of the more complex case (lookup in b)
ids = cbind(colnames(d)[col(d)],
            as.character(e$state[row(d)]),
            as.character(e$region[row(d)])
           )
vals=bt[ids]; dim(vals)=dim(d)
# and compute your desired result with the ifelse
result = ifelse(d==0,at[colnames(d)[col(d)]],vals)
# and that's it!
```

This should be faster (avoiding the nested loops), but I haven't profiled that. Let us know how that works for you on the full data

Comment: Thank you @amit, it works beautifully and WAY faster than the nested loops (tried on 1000 rows of the data). `elapsed: 
nstloop     18.39
index        0.06 `

Comment: OMG! it ran on the entire data set in 3.64 seconds! My `for loop` has been running since yesterday, 24h+! Thank you all very much for your help.

Answer (score 0):

```
# This will require a couple of merges,
# but first let's convert the data to long form and extract year as integer
# I convert result to data.table, since that's easier and faster to deal with
# Note: it *is* possible to do the melt/dcast entirely in data.table framework,
# but it's a hassle right now - there is a FR iirc about that
library(reshape2)
library(data.table)

dt = data.table(melt(e))[, year := as.integer(sub('X([0-9]*).*','\\1',variable))]

# set key for merging and merge with b and a
setkey(dt, year, region, state)
dt.result = data.table(a, key = 'year')[
               data.table(b, key = c('year', 'region', 'state'))[dt]]

# now we can compute the value we want
dt.result[, final.value := value * events.1 + (!value) * events]

# dcast back
e.result = dcast(dt.result, id + region + state ~ variable,
                 value.var = 'final.value')
```