# ifelse not working properly

Tags: r

Inside a function, I want to set a variable to either the corresponding argument, or a default value if that argument is NULL. The code is as follows:

```
  rcontrol <- ifelse(is.null(rcontrol),rpart.control(cp=0.001,minbucket=100,minsplit = 5),rcontrol)
```

It took me a long time to figure out that the `rcontrol` isn't the same as if it were defined in this way:

```
rcontrol <- rpart.control(cp=0.001,minbucket=100,minsplit = 5)
```

Can anyone please explain this bizarre behavior of `ifelse`?

Comment: You want `if(){} else{}`, not `ifelse`. If you look at `ifelse`, it "returns a value with the same shape as `test`" (its first argument), so if you pass it a NULL, you'll get nothing out.

Comment: See, e.g., [is ifelse ever appropriate in a non-vectorized situation?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/8190279/903061) and [if-else vs ifelse with lists](https://stackoverflow.com/q/9449184/903061)

Comment: @Gregor, do you think this is sufficiently similar to those links to be a duplicate?

Comment: @BenBolker I recently clarified the answer at the dupe I chose here to make it more applicable in these sorts of cases, but if you disagree I'm open to other suggestions...

Comment: That's the one I was looking for. I just added the [tag:r-faq] tag to make it easier to find.

Comment: for bonus points: is there a built-in idiom that lets you do `if (is.null(x)) x <- defaultValue` without repeating the parameter name?

Comment: @BenBolker I don't know of a general idiom other than setting default values for function arguments, which seems like it covers most of the times this would be useful...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The key is in `?ifelse`:

> ‘ifelse’ returns a value with **the same shape as ‘test’**

(emphasis added).  Since `is.null(rcontrol)` is a 1-element logical vector, what you get back is a 1-element thing (in this case the first element of `rcontrol`).

You are looking for either:

```
if (is.null(rcontrol)) { rcontrol <- rpart.control(cp=0.001,minbucket=100,minsplit = 5)  }
```

or

```
rcontrol <- if (is.null(rcontrol)) [...] else rcontrol
```

(in this case the first idiom seems more appropriate since you don't do anything to `rcontrol` if the test is false)